# React axios response data does not appear (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, axios

I want to show in table the datas from the api request, but nothing appears.
The data is written to the console. (console.log("Response data: " + users.data))

The response like:
`[{"UserName":"","PartnerID":"0"},{"UserName":"Asd","PartnerID":"3"},{"UserName":"Asd","PartnerID":"3"},{"UserName":"Asd","PartnerID":"3"},{"UserName":"Asd","PartnerID":"3"},{"UserName":"demo","PartnerID":"3"},{"UserName":"demo","PartnerID":"3"},{"UserName":"Asd","PartnerID":"3"}]`

```
const ListUsers: React.FC = () => {
    type ServerData = {
        userName: string;
        PartnerID: number;
    }

    const [data, setData] = useState<ServerData[]>([]);
    const getData = async (): Promise<void> => {
        await axios.post<ServerData[]>(LIST_ALL_USER)
        .then(users => {
            console.log("Response data: " + users.data)
            setData(users.data);
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
        console.log("Input data " + data)       //Is empty?
    }, []);
```

In return:

```
<tbody>
    {data.map((user, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
            <td>
                <div className='d-flex align-items-center'>
                    <div className='d-flex justify-content-start flex-column'>
                        <span className='text-dark fw-bolder fs-6'>
                            {user.userName}
                        </span>
                        <span className='text-muted fw-bold text-muted d-block fs-7'>
                            HTML, JS, ReactJS
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
...
```

What is the problem? Pls help

This code snippet is available in here: https://pastebin.com/bK3X2R1B

Comment: whats the output of `console.log("Input data " + data)`?
why are you u concatting object with string, why not json stringify? or another parameter in `console.log`?

Comment: The output from console:
Input data 
Response data: [{"UserName":"","PartnerID":"0"},{"UserName":"Asd","PartnerID":"3"},{"UserName":"Asd","PartnerID":"3"},{"UserName":"Asd","PartnerID":"3"},

Comment: If I use this format: console.log("Input data ", data) the result is same and don't appear the data on the table.

Comment: the `console.log` inside `useEffect` will always be empty, because `getData` is async func, when you log it in another parameter it logs its reference, so when the `data` state is updated the update is also reflected in devtools

Comment: Ok. I deleted the `console.log(..)` from `useEffect`, but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `user.userName` to `user.UserName` as defined in the data you mentioned above

```
<tbody>
    {data.map((user, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
            <td>
                <div className='d-flex align-items-center'>
                    <div className='d-flex justify-content-start flex-column'>
                        <span className='text-dark fw-bolder fs-6'>
                            {user.UserName} // <-- Here
                        </span>
                        <span className='text-muted fw-bold text-muted d-block fs-7'>
                            HTML, JS, ReactJS
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
```

Comment: I changed the type to:
`type ServerData = {
        UserName: string;
        PartnerID: number;
    }`
and changed in return to:
`<span className='text-dark fw-bolder fs-6'>
        {user.UserName}
 </span>`
But the result is the same. :(

Comment: its hard to solve like this. why dont you give minimum reproducible example(in something like https://codesandbox.io/), so i can take a look.

Comment: The code available in here: https://pastebin.com/bK3X2R1B